# How do I discover my current system encoding?

Tags: system, qt, qt-creator, qt5, encoding

In QtCreator, they have something that looks like this:

[image]

I changed the defualt encodring setting in an attempt to get my ide to display emojis, and now my system is really acting up. Including web pages here:

[image]

Not to mention my software will not compile.
I am trying to reset my default encoding back to what my system uses... but it seems my system encoding has changed.

How do I find out my system encoding, and what should I change it to?

Comment: The command `locale` will show you what you are running at the moment, `locale -a` will show you your choices and something like the following should change locale: `sudo update-locale LANG=LANG=en_US.utf8 LANGUAGE`. Untested by me atm...

Comment: @andrew.46 "atm", I am lost!

Comment: @GeorgeUdosen 'At the moment' :)

Comment: And soon all my english classes will be a waste :-(

Comment: Is it Qt or the browser?

Comment: @Yaron I don't know honestly. I fixed things on the qtcreator end, but my browser wont display this page properly. Maybe it isn't just me: https://www.heritage.org/index/country/hongkong

Comment: Yup, you're not alone, I'm also seeing this, the problem might be the Gotham fonts this page is using: `"Gotham A", "Gotham B"`, when I removed this too the first option became `Arial` and I can see the text clearly now.

Comment: @Yaron Hummm, I guess its just a coincidence then. It just happened to be a site I was visiting right after my errors occurred in QtCreator. I figure it was related.

Comment: @andrew.46 If you want to submit that comment as an answer, I'll accept it and move on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently it's only a font problem with the remote website and has nothing to do with the locale configuration on your system.

Additionally, the browser has its own locale settings and the locale configuration does not affect the web rendering mechanism (maybe the browser UI but nothing else).

EDIT:

## Locales

To show the system locale, simply run `locale`

To see all the installed locales run `locale -a`.

To switch locale simply run `sudo localectl set-locale LANG=<desired locale from locale -a>`.

You can add an additional locale to your system using `sudo locale-gen <locale code>`.

Comment: Fine, but answer the question, as to how to show the system locale.